# Separate some Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro that can separate and save files per column. My problem is this, the cells from the column I want to be separated cannot be saved as ".xls" if cell has dot "." in the text.

For example: DEF. corp

File when downloaded in my computer

[image]

What should I change in my VBA code below to make it work?

```
  Dim MyFile, NewFile As Variant
  Dim sort_data As String
  Dim last_row, tfiles, start_row, ktr As Long
  
    
  'Sort data
  Range(Separate.left_column & Separate.last, Separate.right & last_row).Select
  Selection.sort Key1:=Range(Separate.sort & Separate.last + 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=True, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  
  'Initiate variable
  tfiles = 0
  
  'Loop through data
  start_row = Separate.last + 1
  
  
  For ktr = Separate.last + 1 To last_row
      
    'Identify data
    sort_data = Trim(UCase(Range(Separate.sort & start_row).Value))
    
    
    
    'End of same data
    If sort_data <> Trim(UCase(Range(Separate.sort & ktr).Value)) Then
      
      'Copy and paste header
      Range(Separate.left_column & Separate.first, Separate.right & Separate.last).Copy
      Workbooks.Add
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      NewFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
      Windows(MyFile & "xlsx").Activate
      
      'Copy and paste data
      Range(Separate.left_column & start_row, Separate.right & ktr - 1).Copy
      Windows(NewFile).Activate
      Range(Separate.left_column & Separate.last + 1).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      
      'Bold header rows
      Rows(Separate.first).Select
      Selection.Font.Bold = True
      Range(Separate.left_column & last + 1).Select
      
      'Auto fit
      Cells.Select
      Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
      Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

      'Save workbook
      Range(Separate.left_column & Separate.last + 1).Select
      new_file = IIf(Separate.current_file = True, MyFile & _
       " ", "") & IIf(Len(Trim(Separate.prefix)) > 0, _
       Separate.prefix & " ", "") & sort_data & _
       IIf(Len(Trim(Separate.suffix)) > 0, _
       " " & Separate.suffix, "") '& "xlsx"
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=new_file, FileFormat:= _
        xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
      
      'Close workbook and return to original
      ActiveWorkbook.Close
      tfiles = tfiles + 1
      start_row = ktr
```

Comment: Maybe using `Replace` solve that point. So you can use `Replace(txt,".","")`

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere along the way you are searching the filename/path for a period and treating everything after it as the extension. I don't see any `Workbook.Save` statement in here. Where is `Seperate` defined?

Comment: Hi guys, please check the updated code snipppet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [replace](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php) to modify your string variable `new_file` to be an underscore _ or something. Underscore is one of the better choices in that it allows for double click full selection of a file name (vs using a dash) and is usually accepted by websites and other file hosting systems.

Just add the below line before your `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` procedure.

```
new_file = replace(new_file,".","_")
```